# How to create backend page with specific category?

Tags: laravel, octobercms

I use Blog plugin.
I have `news` category. How can I add item on main backend menu with page where only news will be displayed and I could add and edit them?

Comment: We need more information. It's impossible to answer this question with the provided description.

Comment: @Mateus Junges what info? I need backend menu item `News`. When click on it the list with news should open. News - it's posts with category 'News' in Blog plugin. 
It's in OctoberCMS. Do you understand?

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a way, would need to do some more research and it would be your own plugin extending the blog plugin. I tried to look if you could filter the blog list by a query but didn't see a way to do that.

Why wouldn't you just make your own plugin called news or the alike? Why do you have to use the "Blog" plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom plugin extending and use partials to display data from Blog plugin.
It's easy to create your own plugin other than customizing other plugins.